# Can't load images insade array in sfml

Tags: sfml

I am new in SFML and working on game "Memory Match" 4x4. To simplify I am loading 2 different image.Each time I get the last image on array.Can anyone say me what I am  doing wrong with this?

```
    string s[] = {
        "C:/Users/Eldar/Desktop/sfml/image.png",
        "C:/Users/Eldar/Desktop/sfml/redDie.png"
    };
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++){
            cout << k << endl;
            Cards[i][j].setScale(1, 1);
            Cards[i][j].setPosition(0 + ioffset, 0 + joffset);
            textureCard.loadFromFile(s[k]);
            Cards[i][j].setTexture(textureCard);
            k++;
            if (k == 2) k = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: By `0 + ioffset, 0 + joffset` you mean `0 + i * offset, 0 + j * offset`? Otherwise it seems that you are not changing the position. You can use `i<4` instead of `i<=3` too.

Comment: Oh, I get it. It's the Markdown behavior.